# How to unit test a function that has a condition for the state of something?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write a unit test for a function that has a condition for wifi state. When the wifi state is disconnected, the function returns with false, but I want to simulate a scenario when the wifi state is connected. How do I go about it? Should I make a setter for the state variable? Isn't that a bad approach?

The function I want to test:

```
public boolean performSomething() {
    if (WIFI_STATE != "connected") {
        return false;
    }else{
          ....
    }
}
```

I want to test the else part of the function above, but as you may have guessed, the function executes the if condition, and returns false because WIFI_STATE is "disconnected"

Comment: Can you share your approach? It would be better to comment on that, rather saying anything in the air. :(

Comment: Yeah, sure. Give me a second, I'm already adding it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches that I can think of:

1: Define a sensor's state capturing class say WifiStatus, which your production code initializes automatically through a static initializer.

For testing, you can load a dummy WifiStatus class though a test initializer or change the value of WifiStatus through instrumentation.

2: Use WifiStatus as a interface and then mock it for dependency injection. This approach is more common.

```
public interface WifiStatus{
    boolean isConnected();//
}

public class Performer{
    WifiStatus wifiStatusProvider;
    public Performer(WifiStatus stateProvider){
        this.wifiStatusProvider = stateProvider;
    }

    public boolean performSomething() {
        //if (WIFI_STATE != "connected") {
        if (wifiStatusProvider.isConnected() != true) {            
            return false;
        }else{
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

For test class, you use as follows:

```
public class PerformerTest{
    @Test
    public void verifyPerformSomething(){
        WifiStatus dummyWifiStatus = mock(WifiStatus.class);
        doReturn(true).when(dummyWifiStatus).isConnected();

        new Performer(dummyWifiStatus).performSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example for the second case.

Comment: @syfy have a look

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing any of your code, make sure your class uses a `WifiState` constructor parameter or injection (or something similar).  In your test you can then provide a mock for this object and set the state accordingly to your testing needs.

Comment: Actually, wifiState that I'm talking about isn't actually wifi state. It's just a state variable defined by me.

Comment: And how is that state variable set within your class?

Comment: I set the state in a different function that is called before the function I want to test.

Comment: So you could call that function before doing the test?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about "Local Unit Tests" and not "Instrumented Unit Tests", you can use Robolectric:  http://robolectric.org

http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowWifiManager.html

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowWifiManagerTest.java

Local Unit Tests:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html

Instrumented Unit Tests:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html

Comment: wifiState that I'm talking about isn't actually wifi state. It's just a state variable defined by me.

Comment: OK. The usual approach is make WifiState an interface, then mock and inject it in your unit test. A good mocking framework is Mockito for instance.

Comment: Can you please provide an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for testing, you must be sure for your input how your output looks like because you need to compare them. Make the boolean value of wifi state is injected from outside, so you can mock it how you like. For example:

```
public boolean method(boolean wifiState){
   return !wifiState;
}
```

So now you can be sure that if your parameter is false you will got true and vice versa so you can mock that param and make your tests.

Comment: Can't I just create a setter instead?

Comment: @syfy You can. I told you about dependency injection using constructor and you can acomplish that by using setter too. But, be careful because setter can be called many times on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in with a code-based answer based on [john16384's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947950/469080). You mention that the state is set with other functions within the same class, assuming those methods are public I propose something like this (assuming `WifiChecker` is your class):

```
private WifiChecker wifiChecker;

@Before public void setUp() {
    wifiChecker = new WifiChecker();
}

@Test public void testWifiConnected() {
    wifiChecker.setConnected()
    assertTrue(wifiChecker.performSomething());
}

@Test public void testWifiDisconnected() {
    wifiChecker.setDisconnected()
    assertFalse(wifiChecker.performSomething());
}
```